# Can I use a Swift String Variable to get a Firebase document for a user?

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read some data from my database but I only want to read the data for one user instead reading the data from all Users.

I tried using the variable userEmail to list only a certain users code.

```
let userEmail = String((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!)


    func readArray() {

    print(userEmail)

    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("\(userEmail)")
    //let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the user's information if I type out their user email as "test@gmail.com" but I know this won't work for other users with different login emails.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCXD3.png)

Comment: The issue fixed itself. Just had to reset my internet connection....

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the issue was, I can see you were concatenating the value of userEmail, did you mean that this was failing?

Comment: @pessolato yes that was the only part of the code that was failing, but for some reason today it decided to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed itself. Just had to reset my internet connection. This is very odd but it turns out that you can use variables to find your specific document.